ParallelMap vs ParallelTable: issues and performance for Mathematica 13.2 vs 14.1
Consider the following test code:
code = Compile[{{data, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{sum = 0., len = Length[data], n1, n2, val = 0.},
   Do[
    n1 = RandomInteger[{1, len}];
    n2 = RandomInteger[{1, len}];
    val = 
     Compile`GetElement[data, n1, 1]/Compile`GetElement[data, n2, 2];
    If[val < Random[], sum += val];
    , {i, 1, n, 1}];
   sum], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

Now, consider this test application:
tabreals = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^3, 2}], 1000];
nval = 50000;
ParallelMap[code[#, nval] &, tabreals]; // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelTable[
   code[tabreals[[i]], nval], {i, 1, Length[tabreals], 
    1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ParallelTable[
   code[tabreals[[i]], nval], {i, 1, Length[tabreals], 
    1}]; // RepeatedTiming

I am testing it on Mathematica 13.2 and 14.1 @Windows11. Results for 13.2:

{6.32831, Null}
{0.513067, Null}
{0.258184, Null}

Results for 14.1:

{0.326412,Null}
{0.609678,Null}
{0.258627,Null}

There are a few issues here:

Why does ParallelMap not work properly on 13.2? It is somehow related to the fact that it does not parallelize, but I do no understand the reason. Also, even on top of that, it is too slow.  (basically, I checked that even on 14.0@Ubuntu it works badly, so the problem exists in versions < 14.1)

Why does ParallelTable work significantly slower than ParallelMap on 14.1?

It's important that this is AbsoluteTiming. If using RepeatedTiming, ParallelTable version evaluates much faster - even faster than ParallelMap. My naive expectation is that it is because it caches something for sequential launches. But this is unfair: in reality, the input data tabreals is always different. However, if I am wrong and ParallelTable may actually deliver much better performance, I am interested in how to achieve this.



Probably 1. was just an oversight or a bug. At 2. + 3.: There is always some overhead to launch the job on multiple kernels. But this amount of overhead is indeed weird. You are right that for this kind of workload (in which code performs a sustantial amount of work) all three version and also ParallelTable[code[v, nval], {v, tabreals}] should perform quite exactly the same.

What comes to my mind: The call ParallelMap[code[#, nval] &, tabreals] might make easier to schedule the data distribution. I states quite plainly that code, nval, and also tabreals have to be distributed to the parallel kernels. But it also says that not every kernel needs full knowledge of tabreals. Assuming that every call of tabreals needs the same time (at least on average) and assuming that you use n cores, then only a slice of 1/n of the size of tabreals needs to be distributed to the kernels. This reduces the communication overhead between the kernels.

When ParallelTable[code[tabreals[[i]], nval], {i, 1, Length[tabreals], 1}] is called multiple times by RepeatedTiming, then the required data is already distributed to the kernels. Maybe the implementation can take a shortcut then. Nonetheless, the timing difference is too large to be explained only by this. I think it would be a good idea to contact Wolfram Support and to report this behavior. Quite certainly, they won't fix that immediately, but they might do it in a future release.

Does the behaviour persists with explicit parallelization method, e.g. Method->"CoarsestGrained" ?

@I.M. : yes, it remains.
